# Change fetch type in runtime of @ManyToMany Hibernate relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm using Hibernate/JPA and QueryDSL. I have this tables in my database:

**Proveedor**

```
IdProveedor | RazonSocial
```

**Empresa**

```
IdEmpresa | Nombre
```

**ProveedorEmpresa**

```
IdProveedor | IdEmpresa
```

There is a many-to-many relationship between `Proveedor` and `Empresa`. This is my JPA mapping:

**PROVEEDOR**

```
@Entity
public class Proveedor {

    private String idProveedor;
    private String razonSocial;
    @IgnoredField
    private List<Empresa> empresas;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IdProveedor")
    public String getIdProveedor() {
        return idProveedor;
    }

    public void setIdProveedor(String idEmpresa) {
        this.idProveedor = idEmpresa;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "RazonSocial")
    public String getRazonSocial() {
        return razonSocial;
    }

    public void setRazonSocial(String razonSocial) {
        this.razonSocial = razonSocial;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ProveedorEmpresa", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "IdProveedor", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "IdEmpresa", nullable = false, updatable = false)
            })
    public List<Empresa> getEmpresas() {
        return empresas;
    }

    public void setEmpresas(List<Empresa> empresas) {
        this.empresas = empresas;
    }

}
```

**EMPRESA**

```
@Entity
public class Empresa {

    private String idEmpresa;
    private String razonSocial;
    private String abreviatura;
    private List<Proveedor> proveedores;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IdEmpresa")
    public String getIdEmpresa() {
        return idEmpresa;
    }

    public void setIdEmpresa(String idEmpresa) {
        this.idEmpresa = idEmpresa;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "RazonSocial")
    public String getRazonSocial() {
        return razonSocial;
    }

    public void setRazonSocial(String razonSocial) {
        this.razonSocial = razonSocial;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Abreviatura")
    public String getAbreviatura() {
        return abreviatura;
    }

    public void setAbreviatura(String abreviatura) {
        this.abreviatura = abreviatura;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "empresas")
    public List<Proveedor> getProveedores() {
        return proveedores;
    }

    public void setProveedores(List<Proveedor> proveedores) {
        this.proveedores = proveedores;
    }
}
```

I have this method that returns all the `Empresa` with their `Proveedor` (since is EAGER fetch):

```
public List<Empresa> getEmpresasWithProveedores() { 
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery();
        query.from(qEmpresa);
        return query.list(qEmpresa);
}
```

Now, I want this other method that returns all the `Empresa` without their `Proveedor`:

```
public List<Empresa> getEmpresasWithoutProveedores() { 
        // Set the fetch type to LAZY
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery();
        query.from(qEmpresa);
        return query.list(qEmpresa);
}
```

I have tried to add a `FetchProfile` in `Empresa` entity:

```
@Entity
@FetchProfile(name = "WITH_PROVEEDORES", fetchOverrides = {
        @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = Empresa.class, association = "proveedores", mode = FetchMode.JOIN)})
public class Empresa { . . . }
```

and enable/disable it before each method. But it doesn't work, it has the same behaviour. Actually, I don't understand how `FetchProfile` works and how I have to configure it to obtain the behaviour that I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming you are using JPA 2.1*, You need to use the JPA equivalent of FetchProfile to do the same.

Your class is going to look like this

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "WITH_PROVEEDORES",
                attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode("proveedores")
}
)
public class Empresa {
.....
```

You can run the query like this,

```
  private static void queryWithProveedors() {
    EntityManager entityManager =   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("tutorialPU").
            createEntityManager();
    QEmpresa qEmpresa = QEmpresa.empresa;
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery (entityManager); 
    EntityGraph graph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("WITH_PROVEEDORES");
    query.from(qEmpresa).setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);
    query.list(qEmpresa);
    }
```

In case you are not using JPA 2.1, either you have to get hold of hibernate session and then use FetchProfile or do with the approach suggested [here](http://jdevelopment.nl/fetching-arbitrary-object-graphs-jpa-2/).